# Remove .git and .gitignore from composer package of symfony bundle

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php, gitlab

I've created reusable Symfony bundle placed on private GitLab repository. To share bundle I've also created composer.json file.

When the bundle is successfully installed in target project it also includes .git directory with Git repository and .gitignore file that is totally unacceptable.

I've tried to add archive exclude command in composer.json, but it doesn't work.

```
"archive": {
    "exclude": ["/.git/", ".gitignore"]
}
```

So what i'm doing wron?

How to exclude .git and .gitignore from composer package?

Full composer.json:

```
{
    "name" : "mycompany/mybundlename",
    "description" : "mybundle description",
    "type" : "symfony-bundle",
    "authors" : [{
        "name" : "Myname",
        "email" : "Mymail"
    }],
    "keywords" : [
        "mybundle keywords"
    ],
    "require" : {
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Mycompany\\MybundlenameBundle\\" : ""
        },
        "exclude-from-classmap": [".settings/", ".git/", ".gitignore"]
    },
    "repositories" : [{
    }],
    "extra" : {
    "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "0.0.5"
        }
    },
    "archive": {
        "exclude": ["/.git/"]
    }
}
```

Target project (that uses bundle) composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "mycompany/mybundlename-bundle": "^0.0.5"
    },
    "repositories": [
        ...
        { "type": "git", "url": "git@gitlab.com:mygroupname/mycompany/mybundlename-bundle" }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think that since you're importing your bundle from git repository (custom dependency repository), it's more important how looks the `composer.json` file of the project rather then bundle's one.

Comment: I've added composer.json of target project